# Extracting Distance from FacetWP Proximity Function to Display in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, facetwp

I was wondering if someone could answer a question concerning the use of a FacetWP hook to add distance to page templates (see the last question on this page [Extracting Distance from FacetWP Proximity Function to Display in Wordpress Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403124/extracting-distance-from-facetwp-proximity-function-to-display-in-wordpress-temp)).

I was hoping somebody would be so kind as to tell me where to paste the php code to enable the functionality of the FacetWP hook in the Listable theme?

When I paste the code into the functions.php document the website crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Which code you pasted into the functions.php? You should add only this line in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_proximity_store_distance', '__return_true' );
```

and following function goes into the template, in place where you want to display the distance:

```
$distance = facetwp_get_distance();
if ( false !== $distance ) {
    echo round( $distance, 2 );
}
```

You can see the same answer here https://facetwp.com/proximity-facet-show-post-distance/

This works for me with the latest version of the plugin (2.7.1.1). The best way to ask for help is to open a ticket inside FacetWP settings (the Support tab). They provide pretty solid support. I reported some issue recently and got a solution in couple of hours. In order to enable support you need to drop your license key in the appropriate field in the Settings tab.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following function goes into the template, in place where you want to display the distance: the template's url I have chosen (close to listing title) is `wp-content/themes/listable/job_manager/content-job_listing.php`.

Remember to open/close your code with `<?php ?>`

```
<?php $distance = facetwp_get_distance();
if ( false !== $distance ) {
    echo " dista ";
    echo round( $distance, 1 );
    echo " Km";
}?>
```